# wrong message at specific time

Tags: javascript, time

I have a really simple script to show a message at a specific time.
Sometimes it works, but sometimes it gives me the wrong message and I don't know what is wrong.

Now it is 19:29 hrs and I suppose to see the message what is set in de "else if (hour = 19 && minute >10 && minute <45)", but it shows the message of the "else if (hour =10 && minute <40)"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Below my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FLAPPER DEMO</title> 
        <link href="css/flapper.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="transform/dist/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/jquery.flapper.js"></script>
        <script src="src/flapdemo.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Roboto Condensed;
                background-color: #222222;
            }
                    
            .inputarea {
                display: none;
            }
            
        </style>
        
            <script>  
    var welcome;  
    var date = new Date();  
    var hour = date.getHours();  
    var minute = date.getMinutes();  
    var second = date.getSeconds();  
    if (minute < 10) {  
      minute = "0" + minute;  
    }  
    if (second < 10) {  
      second = "0" + second;  
    }  
    if (hour < 10) {  
      welcome = "Goedemorgen";
    } 
    
    else if (hour =10 && minute <40) {  
      welcome = "10-Stoomtrein naar  Goes                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 16:02        Aankomst om 16:10"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =10 && minute >=45 && minute <47) {  
      welcome = "chips_Stoomtrein naar  Goes                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 16:02        Aankomst om 16:10"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =10 && minute <51) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar Baarland                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 10:50        Aankomst om 11:00"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =11 && minute >=01 && minute <47) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar Hoedekenskerke                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 11:05        Aankomst om 11:15"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =18 && minute >=53 && minute <55) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar Hoedekenskerke                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 18:53        Aankomst om 18:55"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =18 && minute >=57 && minute <59) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar Hoedekenskerke                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 18:57        Aankomst om 18:59"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour = 19 && minute >10 && minute <45) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar Hoedekenskerke                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 19:00        Aankomst om 19:59"; 
    } 
            
    else if (hour =21 && minute <31) {  
      welcome = "Stoomtrein naar  Goes                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 16:02        Aankomst om 16:10"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =21 && minute == 35) {  
      welcome = "Motorwagen naar  Goes                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 16:02        Aankomst om 16:10"; 
    } 
    
    else if (hour =21 && minute <= 36) {  
      welcome = "Pff Motorwagen naar  Goes                 --------------------                 Vertrek  om 16:02        Aankomst om 16:10"; 
    } 
    
    else {  
    /* hallo */
      welcome = "     Stoomtrein            Goes-Borsele    --------------------                            Geen tijden weer te geven";  
    }  
    
    </script> 
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
    
        var myTextArea = document.getElementById('typesomething');
        myTextArea.innerHTML += welcome;
        
        document.getElementById("showme").click(); // Simulates button click
        document.submitForm.submit(); // Submits the form without the button
    
    }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);

</script>

    </head>
    <body onload="submit()">
<audio autoplay>  
        <source src="audio/flapper-crop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  
    </audio>  
            <div class="page">
            <center>
            <div class="displays">
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
                <div class="activity"></div><input class="display XL" />
            </div>
            <div class="inputarea">
                <div class="inline"><textarea id="typesomething" placeholder="Type Something Here..." rows="6" cols="20"></textarea></div>
                <div class="inline"><button id="showme">And Click Here</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a huge difference in `hour =10` and `hour === 10`

Comment: A single equals sign `=` is for assignment like when creating a variable, not checking a value.

Comment: It was so easy. I've made a mistake by setting a variable (single =) and checking (tripple =).

Thanks RokoC.Buljan and skyline3000

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy. I've made a mistake by setting a variable (single =) and checking (tripple =).

Thanks to RokoC.Buljan and skyline3000 !